# When can I add new device after renewing my apple developer program

Tags: ios

I have reached maximum devices(100 devices) to add to my developer account. Right now I have an urgent requirement to add a new device. My developer program expires in next month. I came to know that we can renew 60 days before actual expiration date. If I renew my developer account today. can I get a chance to add new devices. 
  I know that I have to remove all the unwanted devices before adding new device. My main question is "**can I get a chance to add new device immediately after renewing my developer program**".

Answer (score 4):

You can find the information here:

https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html

There it says:

> **After I renew my membership, can I reset the devices I have assigned for testing and Ad Hoc distribution?**
>
> Yes. You are allowed to assign up to 100 devices for testing and Ad
>   Hoc distribution per membership year. At the start of a new membership
>   year, Team Agents and Admins can remove devices and restore the
>   available device count for their development team to 100 devices.

So you can remove devices also before renewing your membership, but they still count to the 100 devices limit until your membership is renewed. You can also find that here:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/658872#658872

> Please be aware that any devices you remove from that list will still
>   count against the device limit until your yearly account renewal.

So regarding your question: It seems to be impossible to add new devices until the membership has been renewed (i.e. until the day where the previous membership ends).

Comment: Hi @Dominique. I have an question that. My membership year will expires on 31 march 2015 but i have renewed my membership on 1st Feb 2015. So the "Reset Device" popup or option will enable after 31st March 2015 or this will enable anytime. After renewed my membership i have not seen this option till today.

Answer (score 3):

As in 2012 Q1, Apple allows developers to remove unused development devices. However, the quota of maximum devices is still 100.

On the other hand, if you think 100 devices are not enough for your projects / companies , you can mail to Apple for adding extra quota for FREE . I have 120 device quota currently .

Comment: Sorry I think my question is not clear for you. I have reached maximum devices. Right now I removed all my unwanted devices. Now I am having only 5 devices. To add new device to my account I have to renew my developer program which expires on next month 21st. If I renew my account now can I get a chance to add new device immediately (today) or it will be after july 21st only

Comment: Do you mean you cannot add new devices now ? ( even you have a valid Apple Developer Account ? )

Answer (score 0):

I have reset all the devices today after waiting for a month.

I am going to share and clear what i have done to reset the devices.

1. My developer membership year is starts from 1st april.
2. I have renewed my membership before a month but didn't get the message to reset the devices.
3. Today (on 1st April 3AM PT) i got the popup to reset the devices and i have reset all my unused devices.
4. If anybody has any question regarding the reset devices option. I will answer it and sure that it will be helpful to you.

Thanks,
V.J.